# What's wrong with calling Application.GetOpenFilename method in Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Namely, I called the following snippet in a button handler:

```
TextBox1.Text = Application.GetOpenFilename("All files (*.*),*.*", _
        1, "Open the Raw Data Files", , False)
If TextBox1.Text = "False" Then TextBox1.Text = ""
```

The error said: "Compiler error: Method or data member not found"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `Application.GetOpenFilename` in Word.

You need to use `FileDialog` instead. Here's a quick example:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim s As Variant
  Dim Res As Integer

  Dim dlgSaveAs As FileDialog
  Set dlgSaveAs = Application.FileDialog( _
                   FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogSaveAs)
  Res = dlgSaveAs.Show
  If Not Res = 0 Then
    For Each s In dlgSaveAs.SelectedItems  'There is only one
      MsgBox s
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm...I'm still having problems with the `s = dlgSaveAs.SelectedItems(0)` line.

Comment: I guess I can't use `TextBox1.Text = dlgOpen.SelectedItems(0)`?

Comment: Fixed whatever I needed to address.