# Insert URL into TextBox

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem of inserting a url into my TextBox.

Here my code:

```
Sub GetOpenFile()

Dim fileStr As String

fileStr = Application.GetOpenFilename()
TextBox1.Text = fileStr

End Sub
```

I want to browse a file and after browsing I want the name of that file to appear in a TextBox.

Comment: Have you tried TextBox1.value = filestr?

Comment: yes I tried it, but same problem and thanks for sharing :)

Comment: quick question: Is this for Excel / Word/ Access or anything else?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10159296/405117

Comment: Thanks I got a answer already

Answer (score 0):

I missed specifying a sheet.

```
Sub GetOpenFile()

Dim fileStr As String

fileStr = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Worksheets("Sheet2").TextBox1.Value = fileStr

End Sub
```