# Addition of Dialog Boxes for File Open and File Save As after Text Replacement

Tags: vba, ms-word, dialog

I have a script that replaces delimiters in a file provided by an outside source.  The script works fine as is, but I'd like to add the ability to Select a file using a dialog, and save a file as something else using the save as dialog after the replacements are made.

I've tried a few different ways found here and in the MSDN documentation and the boxes open, however no data is replaced and no file is saved. Maybe I'm not wording my search correctly. I haven't used dialog boxes in the past :(

```
Sub RosterDelimiters_FindReplace()

Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileContent As String

  FilePath = "C:\ReplaceText\Roster.txt"
  TextFile = FreeFile
  Open FilePath For Input As TextFile
  FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)
  Close TextFile
  FileContent = Replace(FileContent, ";+;", ",")
  FileContent = Replace(FileContent, ";", ",")
  TextFile = FreeFile
  Open FilePath For Output As TextFile
  Print #TextFile, FileContent
  Close TextFile

End Sub
```

Resulting actions preferred in pseudocode:

```
Sub
Dialog Box Opens
TextFile is selected
Replacements Run
Save As Box Opens
File is Named and Saved Wherever
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159216/whats-wrong-with-calling-application-getopenfilename-method-in-word-vba shows how to use `FileDialog`  - if you already tried that then it would be useful to post what you tried.

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I missed that one. :(